# Change the format of cells using formulas

Tags: excel, vba

Hello I'd like to change the format of the cells from my column "I" to "0000" format, using a formula (consequently not using the .NumberFormat method) and VBA.

For instance if range("A1").Value = 09, the formula will transform it to 0009, etc.

I have tried this but it doesn't work :

```
With Range("I2", Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp))
   .Value = Evaluate("INDEX(TEXT(" & .Address(external:=True) & ",""0000""),)")
End With
```

Thank you in advance for your help,
Sincerely,
J.Garry

Answer (score 0):

## NON VBA

```
=right("000"&A1,4)
```

Basically tag on a bunch of 0s on the front which converts the number to a string, then take the last 4 characters.  This is assuming you are working with integers and thus will not be thrown off by decimal points.

Comment: Thank you, this is one possibility, but I'd like to use VBA, because this is part of a program

Comment: substitute it in for your other formula. basically the formula you have in your EVALUAT(...) part.

Comment: Yes, but this mean that I will have to create an empty column, do the calculation and then  delete the other column.
It's possible but I'm finding a more optimised way to do it

Comment: you could load your column into an array, perform a the concatenation of 0s in front then a right strip as you iterate through the array, then dump the array back into the column as an option.

Comment: unfortunately I am not a strong VBA programmer.  I know the theory, but I do not know the syntax.